# Why Spatial Datatype can not hold more than 15 digit precision since it is using Double to hold the data?

Tags: geocoding, geospatial, spatial, mysql-5.6, hibernate-spatial

I am trying to store Geo CoOrdinates inside mysql database Server. If my Coordinate precision value exceeds 15 digit then the value getting rounding off and get stored in the database. I believe it is happening because of [this doc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).

**But interesting info is** *When I have tried to store the same coordinates with the double datatype. I can able to store upto 17 digit precision.*

Spatial Data types also storing each coordinates as a double by inside. Then **Why The Spatial datatype can not store more than 15 digit precision ? I have to store upto 20 digit precision What to do now?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a good question and perhaps someone with a greater knowledge of the internals could answer this, however, I personally would question why you "*have to store up to 20 digit precision*".

I've noticed from some of your previous questions that you're dealing with latitude and longitude coordinates, is this still correct?

Assuming so, the need for 20 digit precision is questionable, and with good reason.  A single degree of longitude at the equator (it's largest) represents approximately 110km.  Therefore:

- 1 decimal place  is 11 kilometres
- 2 decimal places is 1.1 kilometres
- 3 decimal places is 110 metres
- 4 decimal places is 11 metres
- 5 decimal places is 1.1 metres
- 6 decimal places is 11 centimetres
- 7 decimal places is 1.1 centimetres
- 8 decimal places is 1.1 millimetres
- 9 decimal places is 0.11 millimetres
- 10 decimal places is 0.011 millimetres

.. I don't think I need to continue here, at 20 decimal places you'll be dealing with distances way smaller than nanometre scale.  It's worth noting that in reality these distances reduce as you get closer to the poles although with MySQL you're working on a planar model so this doesn't apply (unless you manually implement the complicated vincenty algorithm to calculate distances - which carries severe overhead in comparison to the haversine method).  There is also no equipment on this earth that records this accurately and therefore you'll never achieve a "absolute" result at those levels.

Even if you're not working with latitude and longitude and you're working with Geometry on a planar model, your units can be whatever measurement you want them to be (as long as you remember, convert as necessary and document it - for example metres) and again, 20 digits of precision are just not required.

Of course, you could drop the use of Spatial altogether and manually implement types with latitude and longitudes stored using a type that supports the required precision.  But then you'll have massive overhead of having to implement all of your own calculations AND destroy an benefit to be had from spatial indexing.  I do NOT recommend this approach, nor re-inventing the wheel.

Hope that makes sense.  If I'm missing something, please feel free to drop a comment and I will update my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for the wonderful explanation. Yes, You are correct. I am dealing with lattitude and longtitude (google maps drawing API). Answer to your question : I have to store the shape which was returned by google maps drawing API. In my observation, I have seen 17 digit precision has been returned by the API (in some cases for Polygon shape). Those values has to be stored as it is in the Mysql server. By your explanation, I believe drawing API will not produce 20 digit precision (Now I think 17 digit precision is the maximum). In my case what to do ? Any ideas Please ?

Comment: @user2959196 You are very welcome.  Honestly, I would recommend you simply round the returned coordinates to 6 or at most 7 decimal places.  The user will NOT be able to tell the difference due to Google Map's maximum available zoom.  Google always returns results to maximum precision, but this is more the result of either calculations or floating point representation rather than accuracy.  Additionally, dropping to 6 or 7 decimal places will also bring large performance increases in sending to and retrieving from the database.

Comment: Thanks For the recommendation. I am having doubt on it. Please clear it out. I think, According to our usecase If we reduce the returned data, we might get issue in the functionality. FYI, Going to draw a 20 to 30 shapes(chances to get increased) at street level in a city. And going to check a address with the stored shapes(which we have drawn). As per usecase,Have to check the given address is Inside/Outside the shapes.If inside,need to specify which shape. In this case, If we reduce the precision, There is a major chance to get wrong results. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: @user2959196 I understand your concerns, but as with any "range" query there is always a line that must be drawn somewhere.  For example, if a user was asked to pick a range and they chose 4 and 5, then if a potential result had a value of 5.0000000000000000000001 they wouldn't get that result.  I guess what I'm saying it that in spatial terms there is ALWAYS going to be cases where results just do not make it in, you HAVE to accept that because it could happen no matter how many decimal places you use. See below also.

Comment: Continuing above, assuming you do use 17 decimal places - a polygon (simple) drawn using `POLYGON(0.00000000000000000 0.00000000000000000, 0.00000000000000000 0.00000000000000005, 0.00000000000000005 0.00000000000000005, 0.00000000000000005 0.00000000000000000, 0.00000000000000000 0.00000000000000000)` would not contain `Point(0.00000000000000004 0.00000000000000006`.  But at 17 decimal places you're trying to compare spatial objects at (almost) attometre level (which can never be accurate in themselves).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Jon. I accept your point. Thanks a lot for your guidance.